# Invalid read of size 1 in c valgrind

Tags: c++, memory-management, segmentation-fault, valgrind

I am getting segmentation fault while running my program. I tried debugging with valgrind tool.
Program starts like this:

```
errors_e read_limits_epic_data_from_db()
{
   char sql[MAX_SIZE] = {}
   generate_sql_query_for_epic_cache(sql, db_sys_params)
}
```

generate_sql_query_for_epic_cache looks like:

```
char * generate_sql_query_for_epic_cache(char *buffer, db_sys_params_t *db_sys_params)
{
    char *limit_table_name = NULL;
    char *sql_frmt = "select * from %s where Key %s '%s'";
    char key_epic[MAX_SIZE];
    char *condition = " = ";
    if (db_sys_params->shelf == DS14) {
            condition = " like ";
    }
    if (db_sys_params->hw_vendor == LE) {
            limit_table_name = "CSI_EPIC_LE_LIMITS";
    }
    else if(db_sys_params->hw_vendor == FU) {
            limit_table_name = "CSI_EPIC_FU_LIMITS";
    }
    else {
          limit_table_name = "CSI_EPIC_LIMITS";
    }
    get_epic_key(key_epic,db_sys_params);
    snprintf(buffer, MAX_SIZE, sql_frmt, limit_table_name, condition, key_epic);
    return buffer;
    }
```

get_epic_key looks like:

```
char * get_epic_key(char *buffer, db_sys_params_t *db_sys_params)
{
    char *frmt = "%s%s%s%s%s";
    char *mode = get_epic_mode_name_equivalent_to_csi(db_sys_params);
    char *version = get_on_version_equivalent_to_csi(db_sys_params);
    char *shelf = get_shelf_type_name_maping(db_sys_params->shelf);
    if (db_sys_params->shelf == INTERNAL) {
           shelf = get_internal_shelf_name_maping(db_sys_params->platform);
    }
    snprintf(buffer, MAX_SIZE,frmt, mode, version,
                    get_platform_name_maping(db_sys_params->platform),
                    shelf,
                    get_drive_name_maping(db_sys_params->drive));
    return buffer;
}
```

Valgrind says:

```
=5241== Thread 11:
==5241== Invalid read of size 1
==5241==    at 0x3295847D0C: vfprintf (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==5241==    by 0x329586F631: vsnprintf (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==5241==    by 0x329584F102: snprintf (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==5241==    by 0x5A9BB9: generate_sql_query_for_epic_cache (cache.c:85)
==5241==    by 0x5AA592: read_on_limits_epic_data_from_db (cache.c:239)
==5241==    by 0x586037: insert_on_limit_record_in_ultra_cache (ultra_cache.c:81)
==5241==    by 0x5868B3: init_ultra_cache_on_limit_epic (ultra_cache.c:213)
==5241==    by 0x586A5B: init_db_ultra_cache (ultra_cache.c:248)
==5241==    by 0x59D577: do_sizing (ws.c:3585)
==5241==    by 0x405F3F: csi2__getsizing_json (forward_sizer.c:529)
==5241==    by 0x49D7B1: soap_serve_csi2__getsizing_json (soapServer.c:156)
==5241==    by 0x49CD75: soap_serve_request (soapServer.c:87)
==5241==  Address 0x7802d30 expected vs actual:
==5241==  Expected: unknown
==5241==  Actual:   stack array "key_epic" of size 1,024 in frame 3 back from here
```

MAX_SIZE is defined as :
#define MAX_SIZE 1024

Comment: is `MAX_SIZE` in fact the size of the array pointed to by `buffer`?

Comment: `char *sql_frmt = "select * from %s where Key %s '%s'";` C++ has removed the exception that allowed string literals to be assigned to `char *`. You need to use `const char *`.

Comment: Consider using `std::string` instead of C strings. It will take care of these problems for you.

Comment: The problem isn't fully visible in the source code you included. Your `generate_sql_query_for_epic_cache` uses a parameter `buffer` which the function writes to. I believe this write is broken - but we can't see what you are passing into your function in the `buffer` argument. The other parameters to that particular `snprintf` call look fine at first glance.

Comment: all the previous remarks/question are right. Let `char*`and `snprintf` for C code, you are in C++, use `std::string` with all the advantages that offer, including to avoid the a priori big array  `char key_epic[MAX_SIZE]`  to be in the stack ...

Comment: We don't know where `buffer` comes from, how it is declared, etc.

Comment: added more parts of code, see if it helps to solve.

Comment: Can you log the return value of the snprintf call inside `get_epic_key`?  Does `strlen` work ok and give a matching value, or does valgrind find an invalid read in `strlen` also?

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint at `snprintf(buffer, MAX_SIZE, sql_frmt, limit_table_name, condition, key_epic);`, then print out the values of `limit_table_name`, `condition`, and `key_epic` ?

Comment: limit_table_name: "CSI_EPIC_LIMITS", condition: "="

Comment: key_epic : DataOn5.4Oplat UTA2D480TB\000\355\377\177\000\000\261r\225\225\062\000\000\000\060\316\340\355\377\177\000\000\230\377", '\000' <repeats 16 times>"\262, r\225\225\062\000\000\000X\322\340\355\377\177\000\000\005\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\300\377\177\000\000\032i\205\225\062\000\000\000\062\060", '\000' <repeats 22 times>, "c\317I\177\000\000\b\000\000\000\000\000\000\000"...


buffer : "select * from CSI_EPIC_LIMITS where Key  =  ' DataOn5.4Oplat UTA2D480TB'"